# Need Error Message: Move To code

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a Move to Code. The issue I am having is a result of multiple accounts. I have 3 to be exact.

Let's say - My boss emailed me, so I jump from my work account to my personal account. I read her email, jump back to my work account and run macro. It moves her (last read/selected) to location. I don't know how many personal emails I've moved by mistake because I forgot to reselect the correct email I meant to move.

How can I produce a prompt message stating I'm in the wrong account and if I should proceed? Note: there may be times I may need to proceed.

**Additional Information:**

**Account One:** Chieri Thompson (Personal)

**Account Two:** Artwork Emails

**Account Three:** DesignProofsTAC (work email - the one utilizing move to macro)

*Under Design Proofs TAC is :*
**Inbox** (folder)
**Completed** (subfolder)
**Outsourced** (subfolder)
.....

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click() 'COMPLETED

On Error Resume Next
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim MoveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MoveToFolder =  ns.Folders("designproofstac").Folders("Inbox").Folders("3_COMPLETED")

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Not in Correct Folder")
    Exit Sub
End If    
' this is the error code I want to produce the "you are in wrong account - proceed anyway?" DesignProofsTAC should be "default" i guess.

If MoveToFolder Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Target folder not found!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Move   Macro Error"
End If

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    If MoveToFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            objItem.Move MoveToFolder
        End If
    End If
Next

Set objItem = Nothing
Set MoveToFolder = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess Im wanting the Prompt Message to detect that I have and Item selected in another account's inbox/folders aside DesignProofsTAC and have message ask me if i want to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this simpler than checking accounts.

**Untested Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveOpenMail 'COMPLETED

' Place a button on the Quick Access Toolbar for an item opened for reading.

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim MoveToFolder As Folder
    Dim objItem As object ' <--- May not be a mailitem

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")


    ' Do not use On Error Resume Next 
    '  unless there is a specific purpose
    '  and it is quickly followed by On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Set MoveToFolder =  ns.Folders("designproofstac").Folders("Inbox").Folders("3_COMPLETED") 
    On Error GoTo 0
    If MoveToFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Target folder not found!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "MoveOpenMail VBA Error"
        GoTo ExitRoutine
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objItem Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Use this code when there is an open mailitem!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "MoveOpenMail VBA Error"
        GoTo ExitRoutine
    End If

    If MoveToFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then

        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
             objItem.Move MoveToFolder
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "Target folder is wrong type!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "MoveOpenMail VBA Error"

    End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set MoveToFolder = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing

End Sub



Sub MoveSelectedMail 'COMPLETED

' Place a button on the Quick Access Toolbar for an open folder

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim MoveToFolder As Folder
    Dim objItem as Object

    Dim objExplorer As Explorer
    Dim objSelection As Object
    Dim x as Long

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set MoveToFolder = ns.Folders("designproofstac").Folders("Inbox").Folders("3_COMPLETED")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If MoveToFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Target folder not found!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "MoveSelectedMail VBA Error"
        GoTo ExitRoutine
    End If

    Set objExplorer = ActiveExplorer
    Set objSelection = objExplorer.Selection

    If objSelection.Count = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Select one or more mailitems"
        GoTo ExitRoutine

    Else

        If MoveToFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then

            ' Do not use For Each
            ' Count backwards when moving or deleting
            For x = objSelection.Count to 1 step -1
                Set objItem = objSelection.Item(x)
                If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                    objItem.Move MoveToFolder
                End If
            Next x

        Else
            MsgBox "Target folder is wrong type!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "MoveSelectedMail VBA Error"

        End If

    End If    

ExitRoutine:
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set MoveToFolder = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing

    Set objExplorer = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Namespace class provides the [Accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867142(v=office.15).aspx) property which eturns an Accounts collection object that represents all the Account objects in the current profile. The Account class provides the [DeliveryStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861633(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a Store object that represents the default delivery store for the account. So, you can compare the Store where you chose the item and the default store for the account you need to move the item.

Also you may find the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Store class helpful, it returns a Folder object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the FolderType argument. This method is similar to the GetDefaultFolder method of the NameSpace object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I am not a Programmer and that the code I am using is shared. I did not create it (I cannot write code - but can mix and match fairly well). I guess I was looking for help to modify it to accommodate the goal I was trying to achieve.

Comment: The web site is for developers. In that case I'd suggest lkearning the basics or hire a freelancer to get the job done. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: I see you have given me an option. Its appreciated! 

Though, im not a "certified" programmer - I have written macros. But Only for CorelDraw (for work). So Basics are covered. Im a graphic designer. I got a "brilliant" idea to make one for Outlook to fix this work flow of ours... So I researched it. Found a code that I could work with. Realized everything about outlook is different and decided to seek help after failing over and over. I think i would have been ok with an example.. I do believe even that could have sufficed while I figured this out.  but in any repsect - all is appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to be a certified developer, start with the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx).